# Style select box option:disabled when it's checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the image below, I want Exp. Year (the disabled option) to be grey on page load like a placeholder, and when an option is clicked (2016), I want it to turn to black. It is possible to do this without js?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/216gswqz/)

**What is currently does:**

[image]

**What I want it to do:** (Exp. Month is grey on page load, then 2016 is black on select)

[image]

```
.select-box {
  border: 1px solid $ghBlack;
  height: 36px;
  background: transparent;
  margin: 10px 0 14px 0;
  color: #000;
}

option:disabled {
  color: #a9a9a9;
}

option:not(:checked) {
  color: #a9a9a9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
// binding an anonymous function as the change-event handler:
$('select').change(function () {
    // adjusting the 'color' property of the select element:
    $(this).css('color', function () {
        // caching the 'this' variable for efficiency (give repeated use):
        var self = this,
        // finding the options of the select element:
            opts = self.options;
        // getting the currently-selected option, and then checking if
        // it's the default-selected option (returns a Boolean); if it is
        // we set the colour to '#aaa', if not we set the colour to '#000':
        return opts[self.selectedIndex].defaultSelected ? '#aaa' : '#000';
    });
// triggering the change-event so that this runs on page-load:
}).change();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/216gswqz/2/).

Reference:

- [`change()`](http://api.jquery.com/change/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you. Is this possible without JS though?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because you'd be trying to style the parent `<select>` element according to the state of a child `<option>` element; css has neither parent selectors (as yet, though the [relational selector, '`:has()`'](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#relational) appears to be intended to solve that problem with, or after, CSS Selectors Level 4) or a `:selected` pseudo-class.

Answer (score 0):

When you explained more what you try to do, then the answer is no, you can't do it without javascript, because the color of the main option is just one....its defined by this css selector

```
.select-box {
  color: grey;
}
```

You can only change colors of the options (when the select is opened) - fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/san6q621/

Comment: Your selector, `option:not(:checked)`, is redundant as *no* `<option>` can ever be `checked` (it's strictly applicable to *only* `input` elements of `type="radio"` and `type="checkbox"`).

Comment: I may not have been clear, I updated my question with another image of what I want

Comment: So I've updated my answer to "no" ... you need javascript. I'm not showing the javascript, because there is already one in the next answer.